# how to implement the format for row count

Tags: python, pandas, yagmail

I have a dataframe which has a list of names and email add, for example:
[image]

using `yagmail` i want to `send` a text to the `email` add in `DataFrame`.

Desired output should be like this
mark->

```
sending email 1/3
```

jess->

```
sending email 2/3
```

riza ->

```
sending email 3/3
```

i used this approach:

```
for i in range(0, len(df1.index)):
            print(f'sending email {str(df1.index[i])}/{len(df)}')
```

the output i am getting is:

mark->

```
sending email 1/3 sending email 2/3 sending email 3/3
```

jess->

```
sending email 1/3 sending email 2/3 sending email 3/3
```

riza ->

```
sending email 1/3 sending email 2/3 sending email 3/3
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: Try this
```
for i in range(0, len(df1.index)):
            print(f'sending email {i}/{len(df)}')

Comment: the issue is your for cycle. Every time you count from 1 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

raw = { "Name": ["Mark", "Jess"],
        "Gmail": ["mark@gmail.com", "jess@gmail.com"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['Name', 'Gmail'])

res = [x + '-> ' + 'Sending Email' for x in df['Name']]
ind = [str(y)+'/'+str(len(df)) for y in df.index]

for i in range(0,len(res)):
    print(res[i] + ' ' + ind[i])
```

Above code will solve your problem

Comment: im getting the same output